# Condensing multiple else if statements, referencing them from a table?

Tags: php, if-statement

Hi I'm about to type some 500 else if statements into my code (PHP) which have the exact same coding each:

```
if (color=White);
   rgb = 255-255-255;
   print rgb;
else if (color=Black);
   rgb = 0-0-0;
   print rgb;
else if (color=Red);
   rgb = 255-0-0;
   print rgb;
else if (color=Blue);
   rgb = 0-0-255;
   print rgb;
[the list keeps going]
```

I also (luckily) have a table that displays the color in the first column and rgb value in the next column for 500 of them... how do I use this to save time typing all those else if statements? Some how I have to reference the table file (made in excel, I'm guessing I'll have to save it as .csv?)

Comment: Erm, all your if statements ends with semicolon?

Comment: Hi, I just want to make it clear for everyone that I've just typed this code up on the spot, it obviously isn't PHP and the variables aren't just colors, they're actually product ID's and then the grocery item. ID's are all hexidecimal... this is just for demo purposes, thank you.

Also I'm using for CSV, no arrays etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet is to put that data (color name to RGB value) into a database, then just do:

```
SELECT rgb FROM colors WHERE color = 'red';
```

If you can't do a database, you could use `fgetcsv()` and read CSV data into an array. Then just output:

```
echo $colors[$color];
```

To read a CSV file into an array, use something like:

```
//assuming the first field is color and the second rgb
$fh = fopen($file, 'r');
while (($row = fgetcsv($fh)) !== FALSE) {
  $colors[$row[0]] = $row[1];
}
```

Comment: Hrm, I see your point in database, but is there a clear advantage over CSV? I have absolutely no knowledge of MySQL. What about in terms of speed/bandwidth?

Thanks this is the answer I'm looking for, hopefully it will work!

Comment: The advantage is that with CSV you're turning PHP into the 'database' - loading all the data into memory every time a request is made. That's what databases are for, that's what databases are efficient at doing. Unless your dataset is small, it's faster (speaking of script execution time) to use a database to store the information.

Answer (score 1):

**Why aren't you printing `rgb` at the *end* of all the `if-else`s**?

Frankly, your syntax is **horrible**, this is not valid PHP at all.
Also, you should be using `echo`, not `print`.

```
if ($color=='White')
   $rgb = '255-255-255';
else if ($color=='Black')
   $rgb = '0-0-0';
else if ($color=='Red')
   $rgb = '255-0-0';
else if (color=='Blue')
   $rgb = '0-0-255';
[the list keeps going]
echo $rgb;
```

What I would do is store key-value pairs in an array like this:

```
$colors = array( 'white' => '255-255-255', 'black' => '0-0-0', 'blue' => '0-0-255' );
```

You can then access the RGB value from the array by providing the **key**, namely, the color string: `$blueRGB = $colors[ 'blue' ];`

Comment: Thanks I value your reply, but it isn't just for PHP, I'm talking about conditional statements in general.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an array.

```
$colors = array(
    'white' => '255-255-255',
    'black' => '0-0-0',
    // etc.
);
echo $colors[$color];
```

If you have a CSV file, you could use `fgetcsv`.

```
$colors = array();
$handle = fopen('colors.csv', 'r');
while ($row = fgetcsv($handle, 10000))
    $colors[$row[0]] = $row[1];
echo $colors[$color];
```